# Script attached to Google Form cannot 'openByUrl' a Google Sheet stored in same Team Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, google-drive-shared-drive

I have Google Form that I want to populate a spreadsheet stored in Team Drive. I use the .openByURL() method. This works fine when the spreadsheet in question is stored on My Drive, but when I replace the URL for a spreadsheet stored in Team Drive, I get a null error.

```
[18-04-23 16:06:36:817 EDT] FormApp.getActiveForm() [0.64 seconds]
[18-04-23 16:06:36:906 EDT] Starting execution
[18-04-23 16:06:37:151 EDT] SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl([https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/spreadsheetname/edit]) [0.239 seconds]
[18-04-23 16:06:37:153 EDT] Logger.log([Spreadsheet, []]) [0 seconds]
```

The Form is stored in Team Drive, so I would imagine it has the correct permissions. Is there a way I can embed my permissions in the script so that it will run and update a Team Drive script?

Thanks!

Comment: There are a lot of fun ownership and permission issues associated with handling Team Drive items. Do not assume they are already handled.